# I want to move the typescript object up one level in the hierarchy

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript.
The content of ①props is as follows. I'd like to make it look like ②.
I want to make the object in ① into the object in ②.

```
①
Test {props: {…}}
  props:
     avatarUrl: "/test.jpg"
      id: 1
      name: "test"
     [[Prototype]]: Object
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

```
②
Test 
   avatarUrl: "/test.jpg"
   id: 1
   name: "test"
   [[Prototype]]: Object
```

```
export class Test {
  readonly id!: number;
  readonly name!: string;
  readonly avatarUrl!: string;

  constructor(readonly props: TestProps) {
    zProps.parse(props);
    console.log(props) // ①
    props
  }
}
```

```
export const fetchTest = async (): Promise<Test> => {
  const { data } = await apiClient.get("https/test");
  return new Test({
    avatarUrl: data.avatarUrl,
    id: data.id,
    name: data.name,
  });
};
```

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a loop in the constructor over the entries of the props?

```
Object.entries(props).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    this[key as keyof this] = value;
});
```

Or a static method that uses Object.assign:

```
static new(props: TestProps) {
    let test = new Test(props);

    test = Object.assign(test, props);

    return test;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gApQPYAOGyA3gLABQy1ywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDclNzcNhCZYooAOa8qNOADc4YOFACqUADYiwYkJMoBfSpQRq4GYuiy02BNRCHhzmHPiKk+yKBDh08INQE9aOgBCJlZOHndPb18AgSFQ5FEJKWponz9AuQUlVTVE5J0pdwRfURYEMDwoAAp02MCCFwwmC2dCDABKN2lqAHkOACsISoA6CHAxTBqmjs7RmGqAUUQACxqagG0Aawh-ABpkeTUWCABdboBeAD4e-n4wVeAMHb3kU2Rd-zwYZEfns7IS5HOAnCCpGh6ToQgwUdxYBTABDMCAAdxmzVaTlwczu91sYD+TiBKNRaCcGLmxV6NEglmBA2GY1MGGA4hANTpYEOsyI0MMNLSEDALCgICJWBh+gFpRAll8KGBbVGIDRNXINOyihU6iYACI9ft3NR6EwAAxGmkgQTCZAGy1Q6myyxgVF4EmqsltdXG97ybV5fWG32m5AW33WoRBh38uEUZ14WyjNR4cQ1BWxhNJlNp114aFAA)

Comment: I used Object.entries(props) in the constructor, but
However, I get double values as shown below.

Comment: Test {props: {…}, avatarUrl: '/test.jpg', id: 111, name: 'aaa'}
avatarUrl: "/test.jpg"
id: 1
name: "aaa"
props: {avatarUrl: '/test.jpg', id: 1, name: 'aaa'}
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to solve the problem.
What is the difference between static and constructor?